# Permission to drop table on a schema in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a permission that allows a user to drop a table on a schema, but not on all database, like `GRANT DROP TABLE TO`?

Comment: Have you read [GRANT Schema Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @Larnu: That page is about SCHEMA permissions, the question is about TABLE permissions (or did I read that page not good enough ;)

Comment: You didn't read the OP's question well enough, @Luuk: *"I there a permission that allows a user to drop a table **on a schema**"*. If you want to allow a user to do *something* to an object on a schema, then you need to change their permissions on that schema. Changing their permissions on the table would mean that if they dropped the table, then the permissions are "lost", and they won;t be able to drop other tables on that schema.

Comment: @Larnu: That why I am 'avoiding' having to do anything with permissions and mssql ;)

Comment: T-SQL's permission hierarchy is clumsy, but you can work around gaps in it by using a stored procedure that uses `EXECUTE AS` to do whatever action you'd like to see available, and grant execute permission on that to selected accounts.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation you can notice that `DROP` is not a grantable permission.

The only people who can drop a table are : The dbo, the owner of the schema, the owner of the table (usually the schema owner but it can be changed to someone else), members of the `db_ddladmin` fixed database role, members of the `db_owner` fixed database role, members of the sysadmin fixed server role, grantees of the `CONTROL` permission on the table or permissions that imply control on the table and grantees of the `ALTER` permission on the schema or permissions that imply alter on the schema.